# Статус поста для laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, mvc, controller, model

Сделал две таблицы чтобы получать статус для постов.
Первая таблица состоит из трех полей и называться `Statuses` Поля `id post_id  status_id`

И вторую таблицу `status_list` там два поля `id, status_name`

Связал таблицу со статусами `Statuses` с постами таким образом :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Status extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'statuses';

    public function post()
       {
           return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
       }  
       
}
```

В постах сделал так :

```
<?php
.....

public function status()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Status::class);
    }
}
```

Осталось подключить модель `Status_list`
если я правильно понимаю то в файле `status` необходимо добавить поле

```
<?php 

....

public function status_list()
       {
           return $this->belongsTo(Status::class);
       }
```

Это для того чтобы таблица status_list передала данные в таблицу status, а там их вывела на странице с постами и в самом посте.

Таблица сейчас заполнена для теста,
`STATUS_LIST`
4 строчки

id| Название
1 | **Заполнено**
2 | **Добавлено** 
3 | **Отклонено** 
4 | **На модерации**

`Status`
status_id | post_id
1 | **1**
2 | **2** 
3 | **3** 
4 | **4**

.
В файл StatusController.php я добавлю сл. код :

```
<?php

Status::find([
            'status_id' => request('status_id'),
            'post_id' =>request('post_id'),
        ]);
        return back();
```

И потом в файл post.main я буду выводить сл.образом :

```
@foreach($post->status as $status)
{{ $status->status_name }}
@endforeach
```

Правильно ли я сделал или нет ? или я что то где то пропустил ?

Comment: Ну я хоть что то правильно сделал, и могу получать данные из таблицы `status` но это не то что я хотел, как мне изменить ?

Comment: Не проще ли хранить 4 статуса в константе, а в базе, у каждого поста, хранить ключ к нужному статусу из константы?

Comment: @E_K, а как это реализовать ?

Comment: Ты не правильно указал тип связи в модели. Нужно использовать `belongsToMany` вместо `belongsTo` и `hasMany`, т.к. это связь m2m